# Way to control browser's built-in autocomplete list on input tag?

Tags: javascript, html

There is built-in autocomplete function as a part of the input element in all major browsers. It usually drops down when user starts typing. Is there a way of controlling the list? I mean something like

```
<input id="abc" type="text" />

<script>
    //this does not work, obviously
    var cars=["Saab","Volvo","BMW"];
    document.getElementById("abc").autocomplete.list=cars;
</script>
```

... without using JQuery ... It's probably dream-of feature, isn't it?

Nobody said it is not possible so far :)

Comment: Why would you want to do a great deal of coding writing your own custom javascript when a lib already exists.  Here is an example of auto complete where I manage div's of search results of searching a 10M file of JSON data. [MedaSearch](https://github.com/alexmac131/mediaData)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments try HTML5's `datalist`

```
<input type="text" id="country" list="someCountries" />
<datalist id="someCountries">
    <option label="United Stated" value="USA"></option>
    <option label="United Kingdom" value="UK"></option>
    <option label="Uruguay" value="URU"></option>
    <option label="Brazil" value="BRA"></option>
    <option label="Russia" value="RUS"></option>
</datalist>
```

[More here](http://devproconnections.com/html5/working-html5-web-forms-autocompletion-and-datalist-element)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Wicked!